TypeError: transpile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shots'
Given this code:
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, execute

def calculate_hydrogen_energy():
    # Definir el circuito cuántico
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
    circuit.h(0)
    circuit.cx(0, 1)
    circuit.measure([0, 1], [0, 1])

    # Simular el circuito cuántico
    simulator = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
    job = execute(circuit, simulator, shots=1000)
    result = job.result()
    counts = result.get_counts(circuit)

I changed it a little bit, by installing qiskit-aer, and consulting this question: Unable to import execute function from qiskit library, and seeing this page about the migration from execute to transpile https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/migration-guides/qiskit-1.0-features#execute. The result was the next code:
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit_aer import Aer

def calculate_hydrogen_energy():
    # Definir el circuito cuántico
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
    circuit.h(0)
    circuit.cx(0, 1)
    circuit.measure([0, 1], [0, 1])

    # Simular el circuito cuántico
    simulator = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
    job = transpile(circuit, simulator, shots=1000)
    result = job.result()
    counts = result.get_counts(circuit)

But this code displays me the next error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 29
     26     return energy
     28 # Obtener el resultado de la energía
---> 29 hydrogen_energy = calculate_hydrogen_energy()
     30 print("Energía de la molécula de Hidrógeno:", hydrogen_energy)

Cell In[13], line 13, in calculate_hydrogen_energy()
     11 # Simular el circuito cuántico
     12 simulator = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
---> 13 job = transpile(circuit, simulator, shots=1000)
     14 result = job.result()
     15 counts = result.get_counts(circuit)

TypeError: transpile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shots'

I was trying to investigate about how can I replace or find an alternative in the "unexpected keyword argument 'shots' " in the documentation, but I don't understand deeply what is said. Also I don't want to use an older version of qiskit, as suggested in the answer two of the question given in Unable to import execute function from qiskit library. So, How can I fix this issue?

enter image description here
just like thie，define the transpiled circuit and use run replacing the execute

Answers should use the text, not screenshots.
